# Python Destruction of Tkinter GUI, and loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter GUI that loops, meaning it gets destroyed and recreated or if it could collect names that gets inputted into it.  I asked a question earlier and got a list however, I changed the method and would like now to get the cycle through the same window and when I click finished that it terminates the window. I hope you understand, much like when you input data, and as soon as you press finished, and gives you time to check it.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
class Name:
    def __init__(self, window):
        window.title('Names to be processed please: ')
        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        label = Label(frame1, text = "Enter a name: ")
        self.name = StringVar()
        self.v2 = IntVar()
        entryname = Entry(frame1, text = self.name)
        btGetName = Button(frame1, text = 'Get Name', command = self.processButton)
        btFinished = Button(frame1, text = 'Finished',
                            command = self.processfinishedButton)
        btNotFinished = Checkbutton(frame1, text = 'Not Finished',
                                 variable = self.v2, command = self.unfinishedButton)
        label.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        btGetName.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        btFinished.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        btNotFinished.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        entryname.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        window.mainloop()
    def processButton(self):
        global name_list
        name_list = []
        name = self.name.get()
        name_list.append(name)
        return name_list
    def processfinishedButton(self):
        global a
        a = 1
        return a
    def unfinishedButton(self):
        b = (1 if self.v2.get() == 1 else 0)
        return b
a = 0
c = Name(window)
while a != 1:
    Name(window)
    window.mainloop()
print(name_list)
```

My issue is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8b1e1b0bb9c1> in <module>
     37 c = Name(window)
     38 while a != 1:
---> 39     Name(window)
     40     window.mainloop()
     41 print(name_list)

<ipython-input-2-8b1e1b0bb9c1> in __init__(self, window)
      3 class Name:
      4     def __init__(self, window):
----> 5         window.title('Names to be processed please: ')
      6         frame1 = Frame(window)
      7         frame1.pack()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in wm_title(self, string)
   1983     def wm_title(self, string=None):
   1984         """Set the title of this widget."""
-> 1985         return self.tk.call('wm', 'title', self._w, string)
   1986     title = wm_title
   1987     def wm_transient(self, master=None):

TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: buttons can't get value returned by executed function so your `return name_list` in  `processButton` is useless. Better create `self.name_list` in `__init__` and append to this list. The same problem is in other functions executed by other button and checkbutton.

Comment: @furas I put the traceback error.

Comment: could you explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve? In your function called processButton you have the following line: `name_list[]` which would clean your list each time you run the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to run the code I did not encounter any errors but I also noticed that the app was not really working. I rewrote your code a bit to make your app function the way I think you intended it. I tried to keep all the variable names the same, so you can see what I did to them.

```
from tkinter import *

global name_list
name_list = []

class Name(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.create_window()

    def create_window(self):
        label = Label(self.master, text="Enter a name: ")
        self.entryname = Entry(self.master)
        btGetName = Button(self.master, text='Get Name', command=self.processButton)
        btFinished = Button(self.master, text='Finished', command=self.master.destroy)
        label.grid(row=1, column=2)
        btGetName.grid(row=1, column=3)
        btFinished.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.entryname.grid(row=3, column=1)

    def processButton(self):
        name = self.entryname.get()
        name_list.append(str(name))
        self.entryname.delete(0, END)


window = Tk()
window.title('Names to be processed please: ')
app = Name(master=window)
app.mainloop()

print(name_list)
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: You have helped me so much thanks you, do you have a source where you learned how to do that, because I did it the long and wrote an even longer code with more queries as I call them such as First Name, Middle Initial, and Last Name, and Major and so on,  I am using this code as excel file builder where the GUI collects the data.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ is a good place to learn python. If you have any other questions you cant find the answer to just ask again here on StackOverflow, and if you ask another question, just send me a message so I can hopefully help you again!